# Even if a state has been changed, but the view has not been rendered again in React / Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Even if a state has been changed, but the view has not been rendered again in React / Next.js.
Here is my code and console.log result.

As a prerequisite, I think I understand the behavior of useState, useEffect, Promise, and async/await, but I couldn't figure it out any more on my own.

The return value of GetGithubData is Promise, so I'm wondering if that's the reason why the update doesn't run simply because I can't access the object inside. However, if that is the case, in order to resolve Promise, I have to add "await", and in order to do so, I have to change to the function to "async" function, and when I change it to the async function, I get an error if the "return" returns an object, and the radar chart is not displayed in the first place.

Can someone please tell me how to fix this? I've seen a few similar questions, but none of them seemed to fit.

Radarchart.tsx code is below, which is a component drawing a radarchart graph like this.  And this graph itself is successfully drawn in my browser but the number of commit to Github is still 20 instead of 12, which means the result of useEffect is not rendered again.

[image: Radarchart Graph]

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  Chart,
  LineElement,
  PointElement,
  RadialLinearScale,
} from "chart.js";
import { Radar } from "react-chartjs-2";
import GetGithubData from "../services/githubService";

const RadarChart = () => {
  const [githubData, setGithubData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    setGithubData(GetGithubData());
  }, []);

  const randomNumber1 = githubData["total"] ? githubData["total"] : 20;
  console.log(githubData);
  console.log(randomNumber1);
  const randomNumber2 = 35;
  const randomNumber3 = 45;
  const randomNumber4 = 75;
  const randomNumber5 = 85;

  const data = {
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [
          randomNumber1,
          randomNumber2,
          randomNumber3,
          randomNumber4,
          randomNumber5,
        ],
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
        borderColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
      },
    ],
  };

  Chart.register(
    LineElement,
    PointElement,
    RadialLinearScale,
  );

  return <Radar data={data} options={options} />;
};

export default RadarChart;
```

githubService.tsx is a service file to fetch data that I want to fetch from Github API.

```
const GetGithubData = async () => {
  const owner = "aaaa";
  const repo = "bbbb";
  const url = `https://api.github.com/repos/${owner}/${repo}/stats/contributors`;

  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data[0];
};

export default GetGithubData;
```

The result of console.log are below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetGithubData` is an `async` function, meaning it implicitly returns a Promise. You are saving the Promise object into the `githubData` state.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setGithubData(GetGithubData());
}, []);
```

You are correct that you need to await it resolving.

You can chain from the returned promise and call `setGithubData` in the `.then` block with the returned value:

```
useEffect(() => {
  GetGithubData()
    .then(data => {
      setGithubData(data);
    });
}, []);
```

Or create an `async` function in the `useEffect` hook and `await` the value.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getGitHubData = async () => {
    const data = await GetGithubData();
    setGithubData(data);
  };

  getGitHubData();
}, []);
```

Comment: Note that you probably need to provide an exit strategy when performing asynchronous operation in useEffect, when the component unmounts. Set a flag in the return function to stop or abort the async operation. There’s a handy guide here: https://dev.to/elijahtrillionz/cleaning-up-async-functions-in-reacts-useeffect-hook-unsubscribing-3dkk

Comment: @Terry Great point, but will soon (*hopefully*) not be something we get warned about in the upcoming React version. Sorry, I can't recall the exact post but I think it was one of Dan Abromov's blogs regarding the dumb `isMounted` pattern and how it's not actually useful (*other than making that specific warning go away*).

Comment: Thank you all guys for your quick concise answer above, finally I got resolved this problem and got 12 which is the number that I wanted to display!!!

Comment: @Terry Sorry, the gist with removing that warning was specifically with regards to the "unmounted state updates" since, roughly in his words, "are ignored anyway", that returning that warning only made devs do weird things *only to make the warning go away*.

Comment: I could not come up with how to use .then method like above...